# How to reload a button row in Eureka

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I'm using Eureka for form. I use a `ButtonRow` that open a segue to a `View` showing a map using *Google Maps SDK*.
I would like, that, when dismiss the segue I update the value of the `ButtonRow` using *NSNotification* to pass the address.
I tried `.updateCell()` but it doesn't works.

Here is what I tried:

```
           <<< ButtonRow("Where?") {
            $0.title = $0.tag
            print(address)
            $0.value = address
            $0.presentationMode = .SegueName(segueName: "GMViewController", completionCallback:{  vc in vc.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) })
            }
```

Address variable is empty before clicking the row, but when dismissed the variable is filled.
I tried

```
    ButtonRow("Where?"){
        $0.value = address
        }.updateCell()
```

When I receive the address so I'm sure the address variable is filled. But That still not works.

Anyone already run into this?

Comment: ["Doesn't works"](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) isn't an acceptable description of your problem.  What is your intended result?  What is the actual result?  What's the difference between intended & actual?  And where is the code showing your implementation?  What diagnostics & debugging have you done so far?

Comment: Hi @nhgrif, as I said, it should print the address as the value of the row, instead nothing is written. Let me update with code.

Comment: When a moderator removes content from your post, don't just put it right back in.

Answer (score 3):

Create variable for your row:

```
let buttonRow = ButtonRow() { /* setup */ }
```

Add to form, as usual `<<< buttonRow`

Update later:

```
buttonRow.value = new_value
buttonRow.updateCell()
```